# taskkill /F doesn't work

Tags: command-line, cmd.exe

So I downloaded Avira, and there's something that I wanted to uninstall in the folder. When I pressed [delete], it says that a program is running it. I tried `taskkill /F /IM Avira.OptimizerHost.exe` and I was in the administrator mode, but it still keeps running.

Comment: Show thanks by accepting the answer that helped you resolve the problem. Turn the gray check mark green to the upper left of the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to also kill the spawned child Process tree. You should add the `/t` switch to also kill child processes:

```
taskkill /im Avira.OptimizerHost.exe /t /f
```

Comment: thank you so much :D